# asp.net mvc - couple lists on page

Tags: asp.net, listview

Can I have 3 divs with lists from database on my page? I'm beginner in asp.net mvc and I don't know how to exactly do it... When I want make 1 list I do:

```
public ActionResult Favs()
        {
            var db = new MyDbContext();

            List<books> lb = db.DbBooks.ToList();

            return View(lb);
        }
```

Then I right click -> make view and check option 'list'.

But what, if I want to see 3 diffrent lists?

```
  public ActionResult Favs()
            {
                var db = new MyDbContext();

                List<book> lb = db.DbBooks.ToList();
                List<magazine> lm = db.DbMagazines.ToList();
                List<author> la = db.DbAuthors.ToList();

return View(lb);
////////how return rest of them???
            }
```

I will be thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a Model class for your return View. (note this is all very rough code knocked up quickly)

Something like

```
public class MyListsModel
{
    public List<book> Books { get; set; }
    public List<magazine> Magazines { get; set; }
    public List<author> Authorss { get; set; }
}
```

Then your ActionResult would be something like

```
var myModel = new MyListsModel();
myModel.Books = db.DbBooks.ToList();
myModel.Magazines = db.DbMagazines.ToList();
myModel.Author = db.DbAuthors.ToList();
return View(myModel);
```

You can then use those lists in your View page which might look similar to this:

```
@model MyListsModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Page;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @foreach(book bookItem in Model.Books)
    {
        // Do something and repeat this type of action for each list
    }
}
```